# memcached for legacy Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

Have been struggling with installing memcached in my local environment (xampp). I'm working on a Laravel 5.1 project as a solo developer (I'm serving up the files using php artisan serve).
I found this repo which supposedly has the .dll files (I'm running Windows 10).
https://github.com/lifenglsf/php_memcached_dll/tree/master/3.1.4/php7.4/ts_x64

For reference, my PHP info:

- **Architecture: x64
- PHP extension build: API20190902,TS,VC15
- Compiler: Visual C++ 2017**
- PHP version: 7.4.22

I'm basically downloading the zip and copying the relevant files to my php\ext directory and referencing it in my .ini file (I've also tried absolute/relative paths), hence,
**extension=php_memcached.dll**

But, to no avail. I'm not sure what else to do.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

so you have to install the memcached first in yor system and than you have to add to the PHP.ini file. What operating system your using ? For ubuntu here us link for install memcached :: [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-memcached-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: first check that memcached  is showing to the phpinfo() function.

Comment: Hi  Vishwa. It's not showing up in my phpinfo(). The problem is that I can't understand why it's not being read--I think I'm linking to the correct files, correctly.

Comment: @Theocritus, if memcached not show in phpinfo file that means it is not link with your php version. for that use this link for install memcache in window.
  https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/konyfabric/kony_fabric_manual_install_guide/Content/Install_Memcached_Server.htm

Comment: let me know if you are facing any other issue ?? during installation